# unable route to pages after doing build and deployed in aws instance using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-s3, url-rewriting

here in my local my application is working and previously the build edition used to run in docker also but when we moved to aws the issue we arised is some url and not navigating when we try to navigate i am getting 
the link is this  http://www.sometesturl/demo-page

[image: http://www.sometesturl/demo-page]

and other routing url are working and it is like i declared like

```
 <a href="/demo-page"> </a>
```

on clicking it has to redirect and like this i have 7 other pages which are working but only this page is not working and i applied

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true,useHash:true,anchorScrolling:'enabled' } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
```

useHash:True also but whats happening is then the url stays in the same page i mean  if click on the demo page then it redirects and come back to the same page again  like  http://www.sometesturl/#/  to  http://www.sometesturl/demo-page  to  http://www.sometesturl/#/ it even doesn't redirect also if i use Hash is there any config rules to be written for aws instance

Comment: Did you deploy to s3 as a static website or to an ec2 instance?

Comment: Static and what's the difference?